# Word for "suddenly stand up"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For walking/running you have *sprint*, for talking/whispering you have *blurt*. How about *standing up*?

Example:

> He [...] and rushed out of the living room. His suddenness
>   startled me.

Comment: ***leap** to one's feet*? leap: "1.1 Move quickly and suddenly: *Polly leapt to her feet* So: "He **leapt to his feet** and rushed out the living room." Maybe, also, *spring*?

Comment: "kangaroos pronk”

Comment: FWIW, it should be _"out **of** the living room"_

Comment: How about quickly, immediately?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[To spring](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spring) may convey the idea of a sudden and quick motion:

> - To move upward or forward in a single quick motion or a series of such motions.

- he sprang  up and rushed...

Comment: "He sprung from his chair and rushed to pick up the telephone" sounds quite natural to me and that's how I would describe suddenly getting up on one's feet.

Answer (score 21):

The most obvious choice would be ***jump up***:

> He jumped up and rushed out of the living room.

This most commonly implies that he stood up from his seat very quickly because of nervousness, some external influence (a doorbell ringing, realising he’d just sat on the cat, etc.), or at the very least that the narrator was not expecting him to suddenly stand up.

Answer (score 17):

Bolt

He bolted upright and rushed out the living room.

Comment: This usage has become more common since about 1970, but still lags behind the intensified adjective _bolt upright_ according to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bolted+upright%2Cbolt+upright%2Csat+bolt+upright%2Csitting+bolt+upright&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbolted%20upright%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbolt%20upright%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csat%20bolt%20upright%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csitting%20bolt%20upright%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 8):

The only way that I see to avoid adding either “to his feet” or “up/upright” to any of the already good answers or to my suggestion ([bound/bounded](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bound)) would still require providing some context/point of reference, for example:

> He **bounded** (or sprang/jumped/bolted) *from his chair* and rushed
>   out the living room.

Otherwise, I don’t see a single word that includes the “to his feet”//”up/upright” notion.

Comment: I especially like the _sprang_ option here.

Comment: +1 for "sprang from"; "jumped from" and "bolted from" without using *up*.

Answer (score 2):

I like "pop up".

An example of this would be:

> He popped up out of his seat.

There are many examples of this on [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=%22popped+up+out+of+*+seat%22+OR+%22popped+up+out+of+*+chair%22).

Comment: IMO pop up sounds too casual for the context of the question. I pop up out of my chair when I'm feeling jolly and want to grab a drink from the fridge, but I don't 'pop up' when there's an emergency and I'm rushing to get somewhere.

Comment: "Pop up" means you suddenly get up.  It's an action with an extremely short duration.  What you do after that is determined by whether or not the situation is an emergency.  Plus the question never used the word "emergency".

Answer (score 2):

If you really must have a single word to fill the [...] then it's probably going to be a bit of an archaic sounding one.

There is *upstood* from *upstand*

> OED **Upstand** v.
> 2. To rise to one's feet; to stand up.
> 1896 in *Westm. Gaz.* 27 May 6/1 With all dignity‥Alexandra Feodorovna upstood from her throne.

But this doesn't have the urgency, it's just plain *stood up* in a single word.

More urgent is *upsprang* or *upsprung* from *upspring*

> OED **upspring** v.
> 2. To rise, to ascend; to spring or leap upwards; to start to one's feet.
> 1848 Lytton K. *Arthur* vi. lv, Upsprung the host, upsprung the guests in ire—Upsprung the gentle dames, and fled affrighted.
> 1885–94 R. Bridges *Eros & Psyche* June vi, Upsprang she then, and kiss'd them and embraced.

Notice that *upsprung/upsprang* include *to start to one's feet* in the definition, making it clear that this is a quick movement.

So your example sentence could be

> Upsprang he, and rushed out the living room. His suddenness startled me.
>
> He upsprung and rushed out the living room. His suddenness startled me.

*Upspring* is not marked as archaic or obsolete but it certainly sounds a bit 'old fashioned' and I couldn't find a modern (late 20th C) use that hasn't been split back to *up sprang* except for this literary use.

> Susanna Moodie - 1991 - *Voyages: Short Narratives of Susanna Moodie* [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=bJLRAn9RAzwC&pg=PA196&dq=%22upsprang%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CjocVZjQC8rtaJiagPAG&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22upsprang%22&f=false)
> *High on the groaning shore,
>
> Upsprang the wreathed spray;
>
> Tremendous was the roar,
>
> Of the angry echoing bay -*

Comment: I wonder if gentle Yoda ever used "upsprung"? I bet he would have liked it almost as much as I do! Thanks! +1

Comment: @PapaPoule That inversion is probably why is sounds so old fashioned - Confused might Yoda get and it modernise!

Comment: This is perfect, albeit archaic.

Answer (score 2):

"Catapulted" might work if you want to convey a sense of extreme energy, in a modern context. (Think of a heavy jet on an aircraft carrier, accelerating from stationary to flying speed in a few hundred feet.)

Answer (score 1):

How about: **stood abruptly**

Basically phrases/words that imply a quick motion and that can be used in the connotation of an upward one: say, **jolt**

Comment: Jolted’s worth an upvote IMO, even though when I think of “jolted” it’s usually in the context of someone “being” jolted by something or someone else and not people jolting themselves, but then again I do eventually need to jolt myself out of this chair and get back to work! +1

Answer (score 1):

I like "leapt" the best, but here's a famous example (The beginning of 
*A Visit from St. Nicholas*
By Clement Clarke Moore):

*'Twas the night before Christmas, when all through the house

Not a creature was stirring, not even a mouse;

The stockings were hung by the chimney with care,

In hopes that St. Nicholas soon would be there;

The children were nestled all snug in their beds;

While visions of sugar-plums danced in their heads;

And mamma in her 'kerchief, and I in my cap,

Had just settled our brains for a long winter's nap,

When out on the lawn there arose such a clatter,

**I sprang from my bed to see what was the matter.**

Away to the window I flew like a flash,

Tore open the shutters and threw up the sash.*

Answer (score 0):

He "burst up" would work.

From dictionary.com:

> to issue forth suddenly and forcibly, as from confinement or through an obstacle: Oil burst to the surface. He burst through the doorway.