# What's the word for "swiftly lifting upper body upwards"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The closest definition I got was from [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236922/word-for-suddenly-stand-up)

However, there it implies more like 'swiftly stand up from bed and go do stuff'. In my context, I'm looking more for "being in laying position, then **suddenly lift upper body, while remaining in bed**, changing themselves to sitting position"

Is example from above applicable for my case? Or is there another word/phrase for it?

Comment: Sit up: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sit+up

Comment: @michael.hor257k Why not put that as an answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest ***bolt upright***

From the Oxford Living Dictionaries:

> ***[bolt upright](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bolt_upright)***
>
> **PHRASE**
>
> With the back very straight.
>
> *‘she sat bolt upright in bed’*

The Free Dictionary gives a definition and example closer to what you're looking for:

> ***[bolt upright](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bolt+upright)***
>
> 1. verb To suddenly sit or stand up from a reclining position.
>
>    *I bolted upright in bed when the phone rang in the middle of the night.*

Comment: Funny, I've done a search of this, in all places but one it's defined as being adverbial/adjectival. One exception is the from the link you provided, the Farlex Dictionary of Idioms, which lists it as verbal also.  There's also a question about this expression on this site: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299092/collocation-bolt-upright .